# Django REST error when serializing uploaded image

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm getting a serializer error:

> "Upload a valid image. The file you uploaded was either not an image
> or a corrupted image"

When trying to serialize an uploaded image
My code:

Models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(max_length=10000)


class Image(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=False, null=False, upload_to='test')
```

View:

```
class CreateNewPostAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.NewPostSerializer

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super().get_serializer_context()
        if self.request.data.get('image', None):
            context['image'] = self.request.data.pop('image', None)
        return context
```

Serializers:

```
class NewPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def create(self, validated_data):
        post = Post.objects.create(**validated_data)
        image = self.context['image'][0] # working with only one image for now
        # image is of type <class'django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile'>

        serializer = ImageSerializer(data={'post': post.pk, 'image': image})
        is_valid = serializer.is_valid()  # it's always False!
        return post

class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('post', 'image')
```

I already tried doing that without a serializer and it's working with this code:

```
class NewPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def create(self, validated_data):
        post = Post.objects.create(**validated_data)
        image = self.context['image']
        Image.objects.create(post=post.pk, image=image)
        return post
```

But I need to do it using a serializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way for this would be like:

Models:

```py
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text[:50]


class Image(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(
        Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='images', editable=False
    )
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.image.name

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.image.delete()
        super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

Serializer:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Post, Image

class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = "__all__"

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = "__all__"

class PostWithImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.ImageField(write_only=True)
    # This is for the GET request or the response of the POST request
    # We can also work with a separate serializer for such cases
    images = ImageSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = "__all__"
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        image_data = validated_data.pop('image')
        post = Post.objects.create(**validated_data)
        Image.objects.create(post=post, image=image_data)
        return post
```

Views as:

```py
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

from .serializers import *

# Create your views here.
class AddPostWithAnImageView(APIView):
    serializer_class = PostWithImageSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

For testing purposes, please use **Postman** where you can upload images with so much ease. The request form should only require the `text` and the `image` fields.

Comment: Thanks but still getting an error "{'image': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}" even though the image is present

Comment: I've updated the answer with the use of the image serializer field for the write and Serializer Class for the read operations. Please checkout. Hope this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @pKiran, who gave me an idea, now I have a working code for saving one or more images. It's, also, quite concise and readable. There's quite a lot going on here with so little of code. Django REST is quite confusing.

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('image', 'thumb')

class NewPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.ImageField(), write_only=True, required=False)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        images = validated_data.pop('image', None)
        post = Post.objects.create(**validated_data)
        if images:
            img_models = [Image(post=post,
                          image=image, thumb=make_thumb(image))
                          for image in images]
            Image.objects.bulk_create(img_models)
        return post
```